# HTML div not disappearing after input is removed

Tags: javascript, html

Basically what I'm trying to do is conditionally show a section of a form. If an input field has either nothing or 0 as inputted, the section is hidden. Otherwise, I want the section to be displayed. While the section does appear when I input numbers in the correct field, it doesn't disappear after I remove the input.

So far, I've tried changing the event listener to listen to the `busmiles` variable after moving it outside of the function, but that results in the the section never displaying. I'm not sure what's causing this problem either since I'm not very experience in javascript.

HTML file

```html
<label for="weeklybus">On average, how many miles do you take the bus/train in a week?</label><br>
<input name="weeklybus" id="weeklybus" type="number" required>
<br id="oppositeform">
<div id="busmodeform">
    <p>Do you typically take the bus, light rail, or heavy rail?</p>
    <input name="busmode" id="bus" type="radio" value="bus">
    <label for="bus">Bus</label><br>
    <input name="busmode" id="light" type="radio" value="light">
    <label for="light">Light rail</label><br>
    <input name="busmode" id="heavy" type="radio" value="heavy">
    <label for="heavy">Heavy rail</label><br>
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
function showFormSection() {
    var busmiles = document.getElementById('weeklybus').value;
    const busmode = document.getElementById('busmodeform');
    const extralinebreak = document.getElementById('oppositeform');
    if (busmiles != "" && busmiles != "0") {
        busmode.style.display = 'block';
        extralinebreak.style.display = 'hidden';
    } else if (busmiles == "") {
        busmode.style.display = 'hidden';
        extralinebreak.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('input', showFormSection);
```

EDIT: Fixed. Changed from hidden --> none.

Comment: I think you mean to use display:none; I believe hidden is for the visibility field

Comment: Oh man it worked, thank you! This is why I tend not to touch HTML/CSS on purpose... lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not declared a "style=" attribute in your DIV element.
Too the DIV style should have a property set for "visibility".

```
<script>
// goes in head
function hideDiv(){
document.getElementById("busmodeform").style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>

<div id="busmodeform" onblur="hideDiv();" style="visibility:visible;">
```

Comment: I actually have it in a separate CSS file, apologies for not adding that. However, thank you for the suggestion to use visibility! It removes my need for the extra break tag, albeit the new space is a little bulky.